# Go microservice: Translating DB models to API models

Tags: go, architecture

For the sake of a quick example let's say we have a microservice with an API, domain (business logic), and DB layer. Let's say it fetches users by an ID.

The code might be organized like this:

```
my-service/
  main.go
  api.go
  domain.go
  storage.go
```

In this case, `main.go` takes care of dependency injection like so (oversimplified):

```
func main() {
    db:= storage.New(...)
    dom := domain.New(db)
    srv := api.New(dom)
    srv.serve()
}
```

With the basic request flow being:

1. Request to `api` Resolver (like `GET /user/{id}`).
2. Pass to `domain.GetUserById(id)` to handle business logic.
3. Call database `db.GetUserRow(id)` to retrieve from storage.

Since we'll have a database model that differs from what's returned/sent in the API there will need to be translation between these, where would that take place?

For example, maybe `storage` defines:

```
type UserRow struct {
    Id string `db:"user_id"`
    BestFriendId string `db:"best_friend_id"`
}
```

And maybe `api` defines:

```
type User struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
    BestFriend User `json:"bestFriend"`
}
```

There are several proposals on how to handle this:

1. Store the API models in their own package, and then have `storage` import them and handle the translation there. (But then everything imports these models).
2. Store the API models in their own package, and have `domain` handle the translation. (But then domain knows about the API models and storage models).
3. Have the API resolver, like `GET /user/{id} -> GetUser(id)`, handle the translation. (But then the API needs to know about storage models).
4. Something else we haven't thought of.

At our company we all agree that we should not leak the storage model through the API, but do not agree on how to structure code to handle this problem.

Thoughts from more experienced devs are greatly appreciated!

Comment: FWIW, the two most common answers to this seem to be either: a single model that is shared (the storage layer translates into `User`), or the `UserRow` is shared across everything and translated right before it makes its way to the clients in the `api` layer.